# REP-501 Unable to connect to the specified database

Tags: configuration, middleware, oracle12c

We are in the process of upgrading our Oracle Fusion middle ware from 11g to 12c. We use report server to produce reports in pdf. We've configured the middle ware. Almost all functions work except a few. One of those is report does not work. The report works fine in 11g. [This](https://aabbcc.com/reports/rwservlet?rpt_info=&destype=cache&report=/tmp/test.rdf&desformat=PDF) is the call to get report.

rpt_info is defined in cgicmd.dat as follows

```
rpt_info: userid/password@tnsname
```

running the above URL returns this error:

```
REP-501: The specified database cannot be connected.
```

The `TNSNAME` was tested. From https://aabbcc.com/reports/rwservlet/showmap, the rpt_info also read correctly.

Does anybody have some ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is in a report, by any chance, a table you query via a database link which doesn't work any more? In other words, it is not a *connection* that fails, but *querying*.

Comment: No, the queries are fine. It worked if we ran it in SQL developer. It is configuration issue.